# Snowflake Timestamp with Timezone issues

Tags: formatting, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I think snowflake formats timestamp with time zone incorrectly when using the documented mask for ISO TIMESTAMP Foramts

```
alter session set TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT ='YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM';
select "last_update" from "sakila1"."actor" limit 1
```

results in

```
2006-02-15"T"12:34:33.000000000+00:00
```

Note that in the output the 'T' is surrounded by quotes, where as I believe the correct output should be

```
2006-02-15T12:34:33.000000000+00:00
```

With no quotes surrounding the 'T'.

Using a mask of YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM seems to produce the correct output, but this conflict with the documentation, and the standard they are following.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does specify that the quotes are optional in the [note beneath the format list](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#timestamp-formats), and just recommends them for disambiguation. However, I'm seeing the same issue that you are. I'm wondering if that bit of documentation is out of date. Either way, I think you're fine using the `T` without quotes.

For completeness, I'm also seeing this in TO_TIMESTAMP()

```
select to_timestamp(current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz::string, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM');
```

Gives

```
2020-01-03"T"10:56:55.028000000+00:00
```

Comment: I think that a value with the Quotes around the 'T' is not compliant with the standard and would cause XML parsers and other software that expects ISO Compliant values to choke. However the quotes should be present when defining the mask, at least they are required in the other RDBMS products I have been working with. I think this is a bug that needs to be fixed or it will come back and bite at some future point

Comment: It might be worth submitting a support case for the potential bug, even if you have a workaround, for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing what the resolution was for the case, please help out the community by sharing the knowledge. Thank you!